# React Component dynamic item renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list component that renders data from an array and I like to pass the component as property to render each one of the items. Does anyone knows how I can pass a class as a property to my list component and use it to dynamically render the items.

Comment: Export - Import . Not via props .

Comment: Actually I can not import it, I want this list component to be generic so any user of the list can specify what component they what the list to use to render the items.

Comment: What did you mean exactly?

Comment: The list component is a library to be use in many applications.So in this use case I can not import explicitly the component to be use as item renderer.This one will be defined by the user class.

Answer (score 2):

`JSX` is transformed by `babel` so every `<Component {...props} />` becomes `React.createElement('Component', props)`

so you can do this

```
const items = [{
  constr: 'Child',
  someProp: 'value'
}];

function Parent(props) {
  return (<div>
    {props.items.map(item =>
        React.createElement(item.constr, item)
    )}
  </div>);
}

<Parent items={items} />
```

**edit:**

you can also pass the reference of the class/function

```
const items = [{
  constr: Child, // <- reference
  someProp: 'value'
}]
```

and then take advantage of the object destructing assignment

```
function Parent(props) {
  return (<div>
    {props.items.map(({constr: Element, ...props}) => 
      <Element {...props} />
    )}
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Great that is simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

You want a reusable higher order component for that. Something like this:

```
// -> Build your HOC
function WithItem(Component) {
  return function WithItemComponent({ item, ...props }) {
    if (item) return (<Component {...props}>{item}</Component>);
    return (<Component {...props}/>);
  }
}
export default WithItem;

// -> Then Implement it
const WithItemMyComponent = WithItem(MyComponent)

render() {
  return (
    <WithItemMyComponent item={item} />
  )
}
```